# Reset/Remove Masterpage style on page layout

Tags: master-page, css, page-layout, custom, style

I have a problem that requires me to remove all masterpage styles from my layout page and add custom css styles to the layout. I have been able to add the custom css to the layout but don't know how to remove the masterpage styles.

I will like to know if its possible and if possible, how can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> To use a custom primary master page in your SharePoint sites, you can:
>
> Customize a copy of the default primary master page (v4.master), or
>
> Create a new custom master page from scratch, and make it the primary master page for your site.

Source: [Customize a master page to brand your site](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Customize-a-master-page-to-brand-your-site-0a57b837-4c97-4af9-a088-fedf3dfd1dd5)

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood your question, you have only a specific page where you want not to have the same styles as you have in the masterpage. If this is so, you can:

1) Create a new master page (let's say master2.master) as a copy of the current masterpage, where you delete all styles you don't want to have in the specific page.

2) In the page where you don't want to have the master styles, find the <%@ Page %> directive and set your new created master inside the MasterPageFile attribute:

```
<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="_catalogs/masterpage/master2.master"
```

Comment: Thanks Xavi, do I then create a layout using the new masterpage after step 1

Comment: Yeap I thought you had this, as you said " I have been able to add the custom css to the layout but don't "... give it a try :)

Comment: after creating the master-page copy, I couldnt create a layout from that master-page, the page layout creation page is not detecting the new copy

Comment: where am i suppose to find this line <%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="_catalogs/masterpage/master2.master" ..... the layout or page

Comment: You will need to provide more information, are you working in VS ? are you trying to do this directly in the site collection? etc. Explain more in detail your situation. If you're using VS try [this link](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Create-a-Page-Layout-(PageLayout)-with-ContentType-in-SharePoint-2013)

Comment: I am trying to do this directly from the site collection

Comment: I think you cannot achieve this ootb, without any code customization, sorry.